# How to iterate through items in select with Knockout to display range values

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Is there a way to iterate through items in a select list and calculate a value.  For example I have the following data

"factors": [
      20,
      40,
      60,
      80,
      100
   ]

it currently displays  like this in a multiple select list box, I calcuate level in the HTML statement
Level 0: 20
Level 1: 40
Level 2: 60
Level 3: 80
Level 4: 100

I would like to calculate and display a starting value as follows;
Level 0: 0-20
Level 1: 21-40
Level 2: 41-60
Level 3: 61-80
Level 4: 81-100

How can I get back to a previous level in knockout as I display the current level.  For example in the select list box, I'm displaying  100 and the prevous level is 80, but when I display 100, i'd like to display previous level + 1 and current level of 100 for,
Level 4: 81-100

The values could be changed by the user, so they could enter factors of 15, 45, 70, 80, 100 .  I would then want to display a range value based on these number, ex. 0-15, 16-45 etc.

Any way to do this in knockout/javascript/html

HTML:

```
 <select id="factorsSelect" multiple="multiple" size="10" data-bind="options:factors, selectedOptions:selectedFactors, 
          optionsText: function(factor) {return 'Level ' + factors().indexOf(factor) + ': ' + factor}"></select>
```

JavaScript:

```
   function FactorInfo(projectid, adjustmentfactor, listpoints) {
    this.projectid = ko.observable(projectid);
    this.adjustmentfactor = ko.observable(adjustmentfactor);
    this.listpoints = ko.observableArray(listpoints);


    this.displayFactorName = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        return this.projectid() + " -- " + this.adjustmentfactor();
    }, this);
}


    // Factor construction
    var Factor = function () {
        this.factor = ko.observable();
    };
   // get project trusted data from wcf service
    $.getJSON("../../Home/GetProjectTrustSettings", function (jsonData) {
        var mappedGlobal = $.map(jsonData, function (item) {
            vm.adjustmentFactor(item.AdjustmentFactor);
            vm.mySelectedproject(item.ProjectId);
            vm.factors(item.ListPoints);
            return new FactorInfo(item.AdjustmentFactor, item.ProjectId, item.ListPoints);
        });

    });


     var vm = {
        //app observables
        levelIdSize: ko.observable(""),
        myGlobal: ko.observableArray([]),

        // percent tab observables
        percents: ko.observableArray([]),
        percentlevelids: ko.observableArray([]),
        selectedPercents: ko.observableArray([]).trackDirtyFlag(),
        percentItemToAdd: ko.observable(""),
        globalPercent: ko.observable("").extend({ required: "Enter a Global Percent, between 1 and 100." }).trackDirtyFlag(),
        levelSize: ko.observable(""),



        // factor tab observables
        factors: ko.observableArray([]),
        factorlevelids: ko.observableArray([]),
        selectedFactors: ko.observableArray([]).trackDirtyFlag(),
        factorItemToAdd: ko.observable(""),
        adjustmentFactor: ko.observable("").extend({ required: "Enter an Adjustment Factor, between 1 and 100." }).trackDirtyFlag(),

        // project observable
        myProject: ko.observableArray([]),
        mySelectedproject: ko.observable("1"),
        projectIdChange: ko.observable(false),

        // check if something changes with project ID
        setProjectDirtyFlag: function () {
            this.projectIdChange(true);
            //console.log(this.projectIdChange());
        }

    };
```

Using an MVC format:
Model:
     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Web;

```
 namespace AuditReview.Models
 {
 public class ProjectTrustSetting
   {
    public string ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int AdjustmentFactor { get; set; }
    public List<int> ListPoints { get; set; }
   }
 }
```

Sample Controller Data:

```
  public JsonResult GetProjectTrustSettings()
    {
        //create list
        var trustSetting = new List<ProjectTrustSetting>
            {
                new ProjectTrustSetting
                    {
                        ProjectId = "30729",
                        AdjustmentFactor = 5,
                        ListPoints = new List<int>
                            { 20, 40, 60, 80, 100} 
                    }
            };

        return Json(trustSetting, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Looking for the best way to create the starting range value, either in knockout,HTML, JavaScript. I was thinking there should be some way to do it in HTML, within the function I already have.

optionsText: function(factor) {return 'Level ' + factors().indexOf(factor) + ': ' + factor},  or in knockout as a computed observable or any other suggestions.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

You can create a function on your viewmodel to handle generating the label. If you supply a function to a binding, it will pass in the current context as the first parameter, so you can do this:

```
<select data-bind="options: levels, 
                   optionsText: label, 
                   selectedOptions: selectedLevels" multiple="true"></select>

self.label = function(level) {
    var index = self.levels().indexOf(level);
    if (index === 0) {
        return level.name() + " 0-" + level.level();
    } else {
        var floor = self.levels()[index -1].level() + 1;
        return level.name() + " " + floor + "-" + level.level();
    }
};
```

Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/6qABH/1/) showing how this would work.